# Running into issues when passing struct to function

Tags: c++

i'm trying to pass a struct to a function and running into the error "expected primary-expression before '.' token". I can't figure out how I would go about passing the struct? Any help is much appreciated!

```
void check(std::string buildingName, int floorLevel, std::string drinkName, float drinkSize, struct machines)
{
        bool correct = true;
        if (buildingName == "Snell")
        {
                if (floorLevel == 1 || floorLevel == 3)
                {
                        if (floorLevel == 1)
                        {
                                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                                {
                                        if (machines.vendingMachines[0].drinkTypes[i].drinkName == drinkName && machines.vendingMachines[0].drinkTypes[i].drinkSize == drinkSize)
                                        {
                                                correct = true;
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                                {
                                        if (machines.vendingMachines[2].drinkTypes[i].drinkName == drinkName && machines.vendingMachines[2].drinkTypes[i].drinkSize == drinkSize)
                                        {
                                                correct = true;
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                }
                else
                {
                        correct = false;
                }
        }
        else
        {
                correct = false;
        }
}
```

Comment: Which line shows you that error? What is the type of `vendingMachines`? How do you call the function?

Comment: @whiskeyo All "machines.vendingMachines[]..." lines show me the error

Answer (score 0):

At some lines of your code, you are using vendingMachines as an object of Machines

```
machines.vendingMachines[2].drinkTypes[i].drinkSize
```

And at some other lines, you're not using vendingMachines as an object of Machines

```
vendingMachines[2].drinkTypes[i].drinkName
```

Nevertheless, I don't see any declaration that VendingMachines is an object of structure Machines.

Comment: Sorry, I had to remove a lot of the code as stackoverflow said my question contained too much code. At the top I have four structures: Location, Drink, VendingMachine, and AllVendingMachines. In AllVendingMachines, there is only "VedningMachine vendingMachines[5];". The only other notable line is in the VendingMachine struct with one line being "Drink drinkTypes[10];". Hope this is understandable! Thanks for the help! @Yahya

Comment: @W.Bag Stack Overflow complains about the amount of code when you have a very high ratio of code to explanation. If you need that code, add more description. No Lorem Ipsum, though.Usually you don't need much code and should instead craft a [mcve].